# FFMPEG: undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all' does not link

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, ffmpeg, linker-errors

So I have a very sample code for trying to decode a FFMPEG video stream.
My problem is avcodec does not want to link, to do so I made a clean installation of Ubuntu 13.04. I have build ffmpeg from source following the guide here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

I just want to compile my file. Note that my ubuntu does not have any implementations or header files for avcodec. The command line I use is:

> gcc -I/home/USER/ffmpeg_build/include -L/home/USER/ffmpeg_build/lib -lavcodec -o test.exe Downloads/auv/src/dronerosvideo/src/ar2.cpp
>
> /tmp/ccKTprFq.o: In function `fetch_and_decode(int, int, bool)':
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x36e):
> undefined reference to `avcodec_register_all'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x378):
> undefined reference to `av_log_set_level'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x382):
> undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x3b1):
> undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x3d6):
> undefined reference to `avcodec_open2'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x46d):
> undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x50a):
> undefined reference to `avcodec_decode_video2'
>
> ar2.cpp:(.text+0x534):
> undefined reference to `av_free_packet'
>
> /tmp/ccKTprFq.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to
> `__gxx_personality_v0'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Just for a sane test if I remove the -L argument compiler says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lavcodec
```

Which means that the linker finds the library in  */home/USER/ffmpeg_build/lib*. Also if we check the library for implementation it exists:

```
nm ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a | grep "register_all"
0000000000000000 T avcodec_register_all
```

Also as advised since it is C++ I have `exten "C"` around the include of the library.

At this point I'm falling out of any ideas at all, why exactly compilation fails?

Comment: `/usr/bin/ld` is the linker. You probably meant : 'the linker finds the library in `/home/USER/ffmpeg_build/lib`'.

Comment: Yeah correct! I'll modify.

Comment: hello! did you solve it? I have the same problem and I'm stuck in it.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is C++, so you'll need to use `g++` not `gcc` so that the C++ standard library gets linked. This should get rid of `undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_v0'`.

Then, the order of libraries to link is actually important.
You'll need to specify a library **after** the object (or source or other library) using it.

Putting it together, a command line like this works (in my tests):

```
g++ -o test.exe -I$HOME/ffmpeg/include test.cc -L$HOME/ffmpeg/lib -lavcodec
```

(Actually, depending on how ffmpeg was built, you might need other libraries as well, like pthreads or libx264)

If you got pkg-config installed, it might be possible to just ask that it for proper C flags (`-cflags`) and libraries:

```
# Since you didn't install ffmpeg to a known location, tell pkg-config about that location.
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig
g++ -o test.exe $(pkg-config -cflags libavcodec) test.cc $(pkg-config -libs libavcodec)
```